# Why Curly Braces on Rails Callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I"m learning Ruby on Rails and as I'm tackling concepts I'm also tackling syntax, which is a bit odd when you're starting RoR.  Per Michael Hartl's Tutorial

> When hashes are the last argument in a function call, the curly braces
>   are optional

I understand that, but when the author was referring to callbacks, this line of code appeared:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

I understand before_save to be the method.  Can someone break down the argument for me and why you can't leave the curly brackets off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no hashes in your code. What you're looking at is a block, which is a sort of anonymous function. Ruby has two different syntaxes for blocks. This code:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

...is equivalent to this code:

```
before_save do
  self.email = email.downcase
end
```

In general, curly braces are used for one-liners and `do ... end` is used for multiple lines. In either case, what you're doing is defining a "block" of code and then passing it as an argument to the `before_save` method. This allows Rails to store that block of code in a variable and execute it later, or to pass the code to other methods. Both of the above examples are largely equivalent to this:

```
my_block = proc do
  self.email = email.downcase
end

before_save(&my_block)
```

Block arguments are special. A method can have only one block argument, and it must be the last argument. In the last bit of code I've used `proc` (a shortcut for [`Proc.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-c-new)) to, in effect, save a block to a variable, and then passed that variable to `before_save` as an argument. The `&` tells Ruby that it should treat that Proc as the block argument to `before_save`.

There are some syntax gotchas that crop up with blocks, though. For example, this is valid:

```
[ "two", "three" ].reduce "one" do |memo, item|
  memo << item
end
# => "onetwothree"
```

But this is not:

```
[ "two", "three" ].reduce "one" {|memo, item| memo << item }
# => SyntaxError: unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input
```

When you use the curly brace syntax and have arguments (like `"one"` above), you have to use parentheses:

```
[ "two", "three" ].reduce("one") {|memo, item| memo << item }
# => "onetwothree"
```

In addition to blocks and Procs, Ruby has a special kind of Proc called a lambda. You'll see lambdas in some Rails documentation, where they look like this:

```
scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
```

That's a shortcut for this:

```
scope :published, lambda { where(published: true) }
# ...or...
scope :published, lambda do
  where(published: true)
end
```

...and these are all equivalent to this:

```
my_lambda = ->{ where(published: true) }
scope :published, my_lambda
```

Notice there's no `&` before `my_lambda` on the second line. That's because Rails' developers have chosen to make `scope` take a lambda as a regular argument—instead of its block argument—mostly, I think, so it doesn't have to be the last argument.

The differences between blocks, procs, and lambdas are beyond the scope of this answer, and sometimes subtle, but it's good knowledge to have. I recommend this article for more information: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/64-blocks-procs-lambdas

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces you are referring to being passed as the argument is a block.
The block passed to a callback is executed via [instance_eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval) so that its scope is the record itself.